# Swapping two elements in an array in MIPS assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

I'm trying to learns the MIPS ISA. If I want to do this function in MIPS:

```
A[2*i]=A[2*k+j];
```

How would I go about this? I would also appreciate any other content that I can read, i.e links where I can read up on how to solve this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

We can break this down to 2 parts:

1. Calculate the addresses of A[2*i] and A[2*k+j]
2. Assign the value at the second address to memory at the first address

I'm only going to address (ahem) #1.

To calculate the address of an array element, you need to know 3 things:

1. The address of the start of the array
2. The index of the element you want
3. The size of the array elements

I assume you know how to compute, or just know, #1 & #3.  That leaves #2, which involves simple arithmetic.  (Since you haven't indicated how i, j & k are represented, I can't help too much there).

The final step, then, is to multiply the index by the size of an array element; this gives you the offset of your desired element from the start of the array.  Add that to the address of the start of the array, and you have your element's address.

P.S. The code you're translating doesn't swap two elements; it copies one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a  while, but this could be close.  You'll never learn assembly language without trying youself.  Make more examples and code them.  More study material [here](http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse378/03wi/lectures/mips-asm-examples.html) .

```
# int calc(int *A, int i, int j, int k)
# {
#   return A[2 * i] = A[2 * k + j];
# }

# Args: a0=A, a1=i, a1=j, a3=k Rtn: v0
.text
.set nomacro
.set noreorder
.global calc
.ent calc
calc:
sll $t0, $a1, 3   ; t0 = i * 8
sll $t1, $a3, 1   ; t1 = k * 2
add $t1, $t1, $a1 ; t1 += j
sll $t1, $t1, 2   ; t1 *= 4
add $t0, $t0, $a0 ; t0 += A
add $t1, $t1, $a0 ; t1 += A
lw  $v0, 0($t1)   ; r = A[4 * (2 * k + j)]
sw  $v0, 0($t0)   ; A[4 * (2 * i)] = r 
.end calc
```

Comment: Thanks.  I used the syntax in the examples here: http://www.mips.com/media/files/MD00565-2B-MIPS32-QRC-01.01.pdf  Perhaps different assemblers used different keywords.

Comment: You'd have better ILP with the same mix of instructions from calculating `(k<<3) + (j<<2)`, instead of `((k<<1) + j) << 2`.  But if you have a superscalar MIPS that can only run one shift at a time, you can/should replace `sll` by 1 with `addu dst,  same,same`.  (`add` is inappropriate for addresses; you don't want to trap if `A[]` happens to span the 2GB boundary between signed positive and signed negative 32-bit address space.)