# Swapping elements in array in MIPS assembly? (the clearer one)

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, mips, swap

I know there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924662/swapping-two-elements-in-an-array-in-mips-assembly). I'd like to think of it as a continuation of that question but more thorough.

Here is the relevant pieces of a C code which I want to **translate to MIPS**:

```
int a = [100];
...
j = 0;
while (j<50){
    if (a[j] > a[99-j]) {
        tmp = a[99-j];
        a[99-j] = a[j];
        a[j] = tmp;
    }
    j = j+1;
}
```

(So it's basically works like reverse)

So far I have done in **MIPS**:

```
    .data
array:  .word 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85, 84, 83, 82, 81, 80,
     79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 61, 60,
     59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40,
     39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20,
     19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1,0
    .text
    .globl main
main:   
    la  $s1, array  # $s1 = array address
    la  $s3, array
    li  $s0, 0      # j = 0
    lw  $t0, 0($s1) # $t0 = a[0]
    lw  $t1, 396($s3)   # $t1 = a[99]

while:  beq $s0, 50, end    # break from while loop once j = 50

if: blt $t0, $t1, iterj # if the if statement not satisfied, branch to iterj
    sw  $t1, 0($s1) # write to a[99-j]
    sw  $t0, 396($s1)   # write to a[j]

iterj:  addi    $s0, $s0, 1 # increment j
    addi    $s1, $s1, 4 # increment source address starting with j = 0
    addi    $s3, $s3, -4    # decrement source address starting with j = 99
    lw  $t0, 0($s1) 
    lw  $t1, 396($s3)   
    j   while
end:
```

**Summary** of what I did in MIPS:

Basically, I tried to initialise the array in $s1 and tried my best to make swaps on it. Then I realised that I also need to increment the source address at a[0] and at the same time decrement the source address at a[99]. So I was thinking I can't use just 1 array, which I then made an identical array in $s3 to handle it:

```
addi    $s1, $s1, 4 # increment source address starting with j = 0
addi    $s3, $s3, -4    # decrement source address starting with j = 99
```

Now is the part I need help:

The code works (swapping correctly) sequentially from 0 to 31 (all in hex form shown in MARS) then 31 to 1 then suddenly 63 to 47. There's obviously something I'm doing wrong. **All I just need it to do is return 0 to 63 (in hex) or 0 to 99 (in dec) via swapping**. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're wrong about requiring two arrays, however it is that you came to such a conclusion. Remember that anything that can be written in C can certainly be written in assembly, so the C code you provided should serve as a model.

---EDIT

What I would suggest first is load the address of the array, and calculate the end address.

```
la   $t0 array
addi $t1 $t0 396 #last element of array
```

Then in the body of the loop:

```
lw  $t2 0($t0)
lw  $t3 0($t1)
sw  $t2 0($t1)
sw  $t3 0($t0)

addi $t0 $t0 4 
addi $t1 $t1 -4
blt  $t0 $t1 loop
```

Comment: I didn't come to such conclusion.. it's because I didn't know what else to do. How would you swap the values then?

Comment: I tried translating exactly using third variable but I have trouble incrementing and decrementing the source address... which is why i have to use 2 arrays instead of 1? do you get me? maybe it will be easier if you just showed me corrections

Comment: I totally forgot you can point the address of the last element like that == (addi $t1 $t0 396)